# javascript expression seperated by ,

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this javascript statement:

```
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
```

I don't understand the expression *f(y), x*. With some experimenting I found out that this is working too: *f(y(x))*. It gives the exact same result (for my example at least and is much more understandable to me).

```
  const pipe1 = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
  const pipe2 = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y(x)));
  const addThree = x => x + 3;
  const addTwo = x => x + 2;
  let x1 = pipe1(addTwo, addThree)(2); //x1 is seven
  let x2 = pipe2(addTwo, addThree)(2); //x2 is seven
```

Then I thought that this is some syntax sugar for *x,y* for *x(y)* and tried this:

```
 let z = n => addThree, n; //addThree(n)? no, that does not work!
```

I need some light on the expression *f(y), x)*. Yes I read some stackoverflow articles that the expression is evaluated form left to right and the last is returned. It just makes no sense to me in this example.

Comment: Look at the syntax of `.reduce()`. It's not syntactic sugar. That's the syntax.

Comment: Tnx, yes now I see. it es the second parameter to reduce.

Comment: Expressions are sometimes hard to read, x does not belong to the expression but is the second parameter to reduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x)
```

If you format it, it might make more sense.

```
fns.reduce(
  (y, f) => f(y), 
  x
)
```

So `(y, f) => f(y)` is the first parameter to reduce (the *reducer function*), and `x` is the 2nd parameter to `reduce`, which is the initial value.

In conclusion, you were thrown off by the lack of grouping with the arrow function. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Value-X" is going to be the x variable, passed as the 2nd parameter to the reduce function.

```
    const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
    const foo = pipe(func1, func2, func3);
    foo("Value-X");
```

The expression can be rewritten as this, if it helps to clarify things:

```
    function pipe(...fns) {
        return function (x) {
            function chain(y, f) {
                // y = previous return value
                // If this is the first time the function is called, y = x
                return f(y);
            }
            return fns.reduce(chain, x);
        }
    }
```